# When my server starts it throws Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

When I start my app, I always get this error. After some time, whilst reloading my react app, this error will disappear and in the console it will say "HMR connected".

Why does this happen at the start? What is the issue?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. I suspect this is coming from a call to `JSON.parse` but more context is needed to resolve this error.

Comment: Sure Danny Delott, I will post full stack trace

Comment: In my console I can see only one single statement
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <         bundle.js:1

when I refer to that line its showing the 1st line of html pahe i.e.,<!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens if you have an API call that resolves to some 500 error html document instead of the JSON response you were anticipating.

Double check that your endpoints are returning the data you think they are.